# \rput does rotate my whole document

Tags: pstricks, rotating, ghostscript

When using `\rput`with the rotation parameter it seems to rotate my whole document if the rotated text is longer then the non-rotated text.

See this minimal example:

```
\documentclass[dvips]{article}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont
\psset{xunit=1cm,yunit=1cm,runit=1cm}
\psset{linewidth=1pt}
\begin{pspicture}(16,11)
    \psframe[fillstyle=solid](16,11)

    % Koordinaten Unten
    \psline[linewidth=2pt]{<->}(1,0.5)(15,0.5)
    \rput(8,0.2){\textbf{HText1}}
    \rput[l](3,0.7){HText2}
    \rput[r](13,0.7){HText3}

    % Koordinaten Seite
    \psline[linewidth=2pt]{<->}(0.5,1)(0.5,10)
    \rput[l]{90}(0.75,2){VText1}
    \rput[r]{90}(0.75,9){VText2}
    %\rput{90}(0.25,5.5){\textbf{VText3}} % This does the right thing
    \rput{90}(0.25,5.5){\textbf{VText3 Rotate}} % This leads to rotation
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

So if the short text (VText3) is printed, the document has the right rotation. If the long text (VText3 Rotate) is printed, the document rotates.

Is there a way to shut this down?

Comment: You can also invoke GhostScript directly: `gswin64c -dAutoRotatePages=/None -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o outputfile.pdf inputfile.ps` and no need to change `=` to `#` for this direct method. If you use GhostScript 32 bit then replace `gswin64c` with `gswin32c`.

Comment: that ignores the compatibility setting in `ps2pdf`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it is a problem with GhostScript which is too clever here and thought that it should rotate the page. Use

```
ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages=/None <file.ps>
```

or for Windows:

```
ps2pdf -dAutoRotatePages#/None <file.ps>
```